# Блокировка на уровне объекта

Tags: java, многопоточность, synchronized, android-threads

Реализована блокировка на уровне объекта для доступа к устройству:

```
private static Object device_locker_ = new Object();

public Device getDevice() {
   synchronized (device_locker_) {
       return device_;
   }
```

}

Вопрос, могут ли разные потоки в данном случае работать с `устройством`, вызывая разные методы через `getDevice()`?
Примеры:

```
getDevice().getDeviceInfo()
getDevice().changePIN()
getDevice().doSomething()
```

Т.е. гарантируется ли в данном случае, что только один поток может работать с устройством?

Comment: [Этот ответ поможет разобраться](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52291878)

Comment: Я посмотрел по коду, в данном случае все потоки работают с одним экземпляром класса в котором определен метод getDevice(). Это означает, что только один поток может работать с устройством?

Comment: нет. Гарантируется, что метод getDevice будет работать только в одном потоке. А весь код, вызываемый вне synchronized-секции, по прежнему будут доступен для выполнения из нескольких потоков одновременно. Если представленные примеры вызываются каждый в своём потоке - они смогут выполняться одновременно (за исключением выполнения getDevice()).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> гарантируется ли в данном случае, что только один поток может работать
> с устройством?

Нет. В представленном в вопросе коде гарантируется, что блок, экранированный с помощью `synchronized` не будет доступен для одновременного выполнения несколькими потоками. А всё остальное - по прежнему может выполняться параллельно.

В целом, код

```
getDevice().getDeviceInfo()
getDevice().changePIN()
getDevice().doSomething()
```

эквивалентен следующему:

```
device = getDevice(); // этот код всегда будет выполняться только одним потоком *.
device.getDeviceInfo(); // а здесь уже разрешено параллельное выполнение
// аналогично - для других примеров вызовов методов
```

- Строго говоря, этот код не является полным аналогом примеров выше. Первая строчка "эквивалента" не полностью будет выполнена в рамках одного потока. **Присвоение** результата работы метода `getDevice()` уже не ограничено ключевым словом `synchronized`, поэтому если device является разделяемой переменной - потоки станут конкурировать за её заполнение.

Если внутри методов `getDeviceInfo()`, `doSomething()`, etc... производятся действия, параллельное выполнение которых несколькими потоками может привести к нежелательным последствиям (например - отправка команд на устройство потенциально может привести к смешению данных и как следствие - к ошибке протокола обмена) - именно эти действия необходимо ограничивать выполнением в рамках одного потока.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ.